# how to replace dbms_reputil.from_remote in oracle 12.2.0.1 since All objects removed except REPLICATION_IS_ON, _OFF and _ON

Tags: oracle, migration, oracle-12c, sysdba

how to replace dbms_reputil.from_remote in oracle 12.2.0.1  since All objects removed except REPLICATION_IS_ON, _OFF and _ON

Answer (score 0):

[Desupport of Advanced Replication](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/upgrd/desupported-features-oracle-database-12c-r2.html#GUID-32AC17C8-B9CB-44D5-B6B6-CB8D1AA8E307)

> Starting in Oracle Database 12c release 2 (12.2), the Advanced
>   Replication feature of Oracle Database is desupported.
>
> The Oracle Database Advanced Replication feature is desupported in its
>   entirety. The desupport of this feature includes all functionality
>   associated with this feature: multimaster replication, updateable
>   materialized views, hierarchical materialized views, and deployment
>   templates. Read-only materialized views are still supported with basic
>   replication.
>
> Oracle recommends that you replace your use of Advanced Replication
>   with Oracle GoldenGate.

Comment: Yes i know it's desupported from 12c onwards, but how can i rewrite the above trigger without affecting the application logic,